# Bootstrap Nav Tab Click Event Works EXCEPT on Tab Label Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, events

Hello I've been poking at this for about 1/2 hour - it seems trivial perhaps but I want to deliver well for the client on this one.

We've got a form set up with sections inside of a sequence of tabs. For now I'm just trying to make the 'Save and Continue' button change to 'Submit' when the last tab is made active - either by the user hitting the 'Save and Continue' button or by clicking the tabs at top - later we'll be adding submission validation, etc. But I figure that having the button text-change working will get me familiar enough with what was built (by sommeone else) to get the more complex stuff working later.

**What's working**:

- The button changes name perfectly when the user arrives at the final tab by clicking the button.
- The button changes name perfectly when the user clicks on the last tab... EXCEPT when they click on the actual text *inside* the tab. The click event is still generated, but the console call for the e.target.id throws an empty string.

Code for the Nav-tabs:

```html
             <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li id="personalInfoTab" role="presentation" class="active"><a id="personalInfoLink" href="#personal-info" aria-controls="personal-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="hidden-xs"><strong>Personal Information</strong></a><a href="#personal-info" aria-controls="personal-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="visible-xs">Personal Info</a></li>
                <li id="professionalInfoTab" role="presentation"><a id="professionalInfoLink" href="#professional-info" aria-controls="professional-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="hidden-xs"><strong>Professional Information</strong></a><a href="#contact-info" aria-controls="contact-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="visible-xs">Prof. Info</a></li>
                <li id="expectationsTab" role="presentation"><a id="expectationsLink" href="#expectations" aria-controls="expectations" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="hidden-xs"><strong>Employment Expectations</strong></a><a id="expectationsLink" href="#expectations" aria-controls="expectations" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="visible-xs">Expectations</a></li>
                
                <li id="settingsTab" role="presentation"><a id="settingsLink" href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="hidden-xs"><strong>Profile Settings</strong></a><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="visible-xs">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
```

Code for the Button:

```html
<input type="submit" name="profile-continue" class="btn btn-danger" id="continueBtn" value="Save & Continue">
```

And the Jquery:

```js
 // Check which tab is active and set the Continue Button text 
 function initButtons() {
 
  console.log($('#settingsTab'));
  
 if ($('#settingsTab').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#continueBtn').prop( 'value' , 'Submit');
 }
 else {
  $('#continueBtn').prop( 'value' , 'Save and Continue');
 }
 };
 
 initButtons();

 /* The 'Continue' button behavior */
 $('#continueBtn').click(function(){
  // Activate the next tab
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  // Change the submit Button text accordingly
  initButtons();
  // Possible to-do: wrap in an 'if' statement that checks if there's any missing 'required' fields.
  // Possible to-do: determine 'if' the tab selected is the last in the sequence.
  // Possible to-do: grey/non-grey tabs (make accessible in sequnce).
  }
  );
 
 $( 'a[data-toggle="tab"]' ).click(function(e){
  console.log(e);
  console.log('Target: ' , e.target.id);
  // Check what tab was picked and submit Button text accordingly
  
   if ( e.target.id === 'settingsLink' ) {
    $('#continueBtn').prop( 'value' , 'Submit');
   }
   else {
    $('#continueBtn').prop( 'value' , 'Save and Continue');
   }
  
  }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured this out just as I was typing up the question but figured I'd still post here to help somebody else who might need it. The tab-text is inside of a 'strong' HTML element, which is a *child* of the tab that I'm *trying* to target.

So I got it working by changing the line:

```js
if (e.target.id === 'settingsLink' ) {...
```

to:

```js
if (e.target.id === 'settingsLink' || e.target.parentElement.id === 'settingsLink' ) {...
```

Hope it saves somebody some time.